# Two identical node setups produce different results

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

I've been following a tutorial and it came to the part of creating a very basic circuit board piece. I've copied the node tree almost exactly as the guy showed in his video but my results look very different to his. I also happen to have his project file, and after thorough analysis, I just can't understand why my circuit looks so dull and his so shiny even though everything is identical.

Is there something that I forgot to press, or am not seeing?

His project file
[image: His version]

And this is mine
[image]

Comment: Lighting, world, UV coordinates.  You seem to be using a slightly different blend weight, and have different render settings, but none of that should be mattering here.  Color ramps can't be verified as identical from these pictures, would need to inspect the stops.

Comment: Can you please have a look:
His
https://blend-exchange.com/b/Z6n555RZ
Mine
https://blend-exchange.com/b/15drSN7d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pack the texture image, but we can see at a glance that your shape has very different UV coordinates than his:

[image]

These UV coordinates are going to be used to read the texture.  Different UV coords, different colors from the image texture.

Your materials are further different in the blend used for the layer weight node, and the color ramps are different, both in the color and position of the stops.  But these are minor differences compared to reading the same texture image in completely different ways.

As an aside, Blender has precision problems when rendering objects far from the origin, as is the case in your file.  This is a known bug, unfixed for a while.  Putting your object at X 125 is probably going to lead to rendering problems.